# Wolfram API "data not available" message

Tags: python, wolframalpha

I have been using the WolframAlpha python API, and I sometimes get the output `(data not available)`, despite it being something basic. An example is `How many airplanes are in the air now?`, which is something that I know wolfram can do. Does anyone know of a way to fix this, or just the reason?

Comment: You should put an minimal example that can be reproduced by anyone.

Comment: Thanks, I've now done that